# Proper use of Native Base Containers for React Native

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm building a React Native app using [Native Base](https://nativebase.io/). Is the `<Container>` component meant to be used once and wrap the whole app or one for every screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One for every screen

Go through NativeBase Docs to know more